# Error running rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, nokogiri

I'm working on a Rails app and testing using Rspec. Unfortunately when I try to run `bundle exec rspec` I'm met with a giant wall of error text (below).

The first line I see is a warning about Nokogiri, but I suspect that is unrelated to the main issue at hand.

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8

Could not open library 'kernel32': dlopen(kernel32, 5): image not found.
Could not open library 'libkernel32.dylib': dlopen(libkernel32.dylib, 5): image not found (LoadError)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.0/lib/ffi/library.rb:123:in `block in ffi_lib'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.0/lib/ffi/library.rb:90:in `map'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.0/lib/ffi/library.rb:90:in `ffi_lib'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-fchange-0.0.5/lib/rb-fchange/native.rb:10:in `<module:Native>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-fchange-0.0.5/lib/rb-fchange/native.rb:8:in `<module:FChange>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-fchange-0.0.5/lib/rb-fchange/native.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rb-fchange-0.0.5/lib/rb-fchange.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/Users/varunrau/Documents/curr/BPSF/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/app_framework/rails.rb:48:in `preload_rails'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/app_framework/rails.rb:7:in `preload'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:134:in `block in preload'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork.rb:62:in `exec_prefork'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:120:in `preload'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:25:in `preload'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/runner.rb:74:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/spork:23:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/spork:23:in `<main>'
```

My system details are: OS X 10.8, Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3p194. I tried reinstalling Ruby and the rb-fchange gem as per some advice on this site, but nothing has worked.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: This question looks similar but none of the advice seemed to help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053918/could-not-open-library-libkernel32-so-running-bundle-exec-rspec-on-solaris-in?rq=1

Comment: Is it possible to comment the code with gem's (rb-fchange) methods and try run specs again?

Comment: Comment out Nokogiri in your gemfile and and elsewhere and run `bundle`.  Will your tests boot up with Nokogiri commented out?

Comment: @tyler I tried commenting out Nokogiri but I still received the error, but the warning is gone. So it would seem that they are unrelated.

Comment: @gotva I don't think that is possible. I didn't write any code using that gem (honestly, I had never even heard of it before).